# Selenium python, multiple geckodriver instances

Tags: python, selenium

I m trying to find out, how i can run and control different instances of Firefox using selenium in python. I m using the geckodriver, to run Firefox. I know, that i can have multiple Profiles in Firefox and that i can run a new Profile seperatly under about:profiles. This would solve my problem, if i knew how i can switch between the windows coresponding to the different profiles. I d be happy, if someone could tell me, how to do that and even more, if someone knows of a threat, where i can read up on it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I know how to switch tabs in general. The important thing is, that they are seperated. For me that means, that i can log into a second different Accounts, without being logged out of the first one. This isnt my field but i think that means, that they dont share cookies and cache.

Comment: You need a thread per driver/browser.

Comment: Ok thanks. I ll look into that. Seems it takes alot of memory, for what i want to do. I dont need to controll every insatance at the same time, just keep them loaded in the backround and switch to it when needed. I d be grateful for further suggestions but it seems threading is a solution.

Comment: you wouldn't necessarily need threading then... just a webdriver object for each browser.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answere. I ll read into it more. For now i ve found a simpler solution, to my problem. I can say driver1 = webdriver.Firefox(PATH) and driver2 = webdriver.Firefox(PATH) and then control them separately. Sorry that i bothered when it was so easy and thanks for the help.